# Exclude rows from dataframe except if another column condition met

Tags: python, pandas, logic

I would like to exclude rows from my dataframe if they meet a list (eligibility_criteria) condition, unless the tariff column starts with '***'. This is what I have:

```
import pandas as pd

df = df[~df['eligibility'].str.contains(eligibility_criteria, na=False)] #This works
```

How do I add this 'except when' qualifier...

```
#df['tariff'].str.startswith("***")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let `E` be the eligibility criterion and `S` be true if the tariff starts with `"***"`. You want to exclude the rows that are `E unless S` which is the same as `E & ~S`. Conversely, you want to keep the rows that do not have this property: `~(E & ~S)`, which is the same as `~E | S`:

```
df = df[~df['eligibility'].str.contains(eligibility_criteria, na=False) | 
         df['tariff'].str.startswith("***")]
```